# Disappearing images ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a problem with list view.

In my app there's a `ListFragment` which holds a list of notifications which are basically a text and an image.

They also might be disabled, when clicked. On click I set a field 'active' of struct `Notification` to false and call `NotifyDataSetChanged` method. But when i scroll it up and down, some images disappear and might reappear again. But not when I don't scroll it.

All images are in resources and i never set visibility of list items.

Here's some of my code:

Custom ArrayAdapter

```
public class NotificationsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Notification> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] message_strings;
    private final Drawable[] images;
    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<Notification> items;

    public NotificationsArrayAdapter (Context context, Resources resources, ArrayList<Notification> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.customer_notifications_list_item, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    this.message_strings = new String[] {"message1", "message2", "message3", "message4"};

    this.images = new Drawable[] {ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.notifications_blue_circle),
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.notifications_red_circle),
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.notifications_grey_circle),
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.notifications_green_circle)
        };

        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_notifications_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Notification item = getItem(position);

        if (item != null) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.notifications_list_item_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.notifications_list_item_image);

            if (textView != null) {
                if (item.getActive()) {
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                }
                else {
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BBBBBB"));
                }
                textView.setText(message_strings[item.getType()]);
            }

            if (imageView != null) {
                if (item.getActive()) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(images[item.getType()]);
                }
                else {
                    imageView.setImageAlpha(0);
                }
            }
        }

    return v;
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class CustomerNotificationsFragment extends ListFragment {

    public CustomerNotificationsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer_notifications, container, false);

        ArrayList<Notification> notifications = new ArrayList<Notification>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            notifications.add(new Notification(1, "blabal"));
        }

        NotificationsArrayAdapter notificationsArrayAdapter = new NotificationsArrayAdapter(getActivity(), getResources(), notifications);
        setListAdapter(notificationsArrayAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Notification item = (Notification) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        item.setActive(false);

        ((ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views in an adapter are recycled. Meaning you end using items with imageAlpha = 0 even if they satisfy the if statement here:

```
if (viewHolder.imageView != null) {
    if (item.getActive()) {
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(images[item.getType()]);
    } 
    else {
       viewHolder.imageView.setImageAlpha(0);
    }
}
```

You should change critical properties in both parts of the statement, because of the recycling. So, it should be like:

```
if (viewHolder.imageView != null) {
      if (item.getActive()) {
          viewHolder.imageView.setImageAlpha(255);
          viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(images[item.getType()]);
      }
      else {
          viewHolder.imageView.setImageAlpha(0);
      }
}
```

Here is an image of how list items recycling works:

[image]

Source: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296 (It also has a tutorial about lisviews)

I also recommend to go with the viewHolder approach (faster and more efficient), there is a google talk about it (https://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70), and you can also use the code Claud25 provided.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but there's still one thing: when i check an item and start to scroll, only one image starts to appear and disappear, all the others are ok. It disappears only when the list is below particular position. Do you know what might be the case?

Comment: there's still one thing wrong with your answer: setImageAlpha is in the range 0..255, so it should be called with argument 255. If someone will have same issue, he won't see any picture at all.

Comment: The image is still disappearing after the setImageAlpha(255)? (sorry, messed up a little and forgot setImageAlpha used an int parameter, not a float)

Comment: Yeah, but now only in one item. And it's always the same item, which is the last when i open this fragment. It disappears when i scroll about half of the screen.

Comment: Well, I don't know why, but when i changed `setImageAlpha` to `setVisibility` it all started working properly, but can't really understand what's the diffirence...

Comment: Weird, maybe there's a little bug or there's something we aren't taking into account. In any case, glad to hear you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (imageView != null) {
            if (item.getActive()) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(images[item.getType()]);
            }
            else {
                imageView.setImageAlpha(0);
            }
        }
```

This is probably where your problem is. I would suggest setting a breakpoint on

```
imageView.setImageAlpha(0);
```

to see if it gets triggered before the image disappears.

Also, I'm assuming your Notification object is not the Android [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) object? I couldn't find a getActive() method on the documentation. What does this method do?

Comment: Notification is my own class which simply holds some values. Active is a boolean constant of which getAlpha() is a getter.

Comment: setAlpha is triggered only for clicked item. Checked this by logging.

Answer (score 0):

The listview will recycle views so I've found that this happened to me before when I was doing something similar where I would change the data and after scrolling it will change the list back to original or something weird. To solve that issue I used the [viewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

Your getView in the custom adapter will look something like this.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null){

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customer_notifications_list_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notifications_list_item_text);
        viewHolder.imageView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notifications_list_item_image);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Notification item = getItem(position);

    if (item != null) {

        if (viewHolder.textView != null) {
            if (item.getActive()) {
                viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            }
            else {
                viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BBBBBB"));
            }
            viewHolder.textView.setText(message_strings[item.getType()]);
        }

        if (viewHolder.imageView != null) {
            if (item.getActive()) {
                viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(images[item.getType()]);
            }
            else {
                viewHolder.imageView.setImageAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView textView;
    protected ImageView imageView;

}
```